# navigate to cur position on apple maps

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have been asked to put a button on my apple map which will animate to the devices current location much like the default button that comes with google maps.

I have tried implementing it but it is taking nearly ten seconds before the animation is happening and I need it to be instant.

My attempt:
I have the CLLocationMangerDelegate in my class definition.

```
class Register2Controller: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, FBSDKSharingDelegate
```

I have defined my locManager:

```
var locManager : CLLocationManager!
```

I have the following for location updates:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("in the update location")
        if (firstRetrieved){
            println("inside first retrieved")
            var locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
            let span2 = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)
            let long = locValue.longitude
            let lat = locValue.latitude
            println("in firstRetrieved function with \(lat) and \(long)")
            let loadlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: lat, longitude: long
            )
            mapView.centerCoordinate = loadlocation
            var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = loadlocation.latitude
            var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = loadlocation.longitude
            var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.5
            var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.5

            var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
            var curLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
            var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(curLocation, theSpan)
            self.mapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)
            if !curBtnBool {
                // I check curBtnBool to check if the user is in this function  from pressing the button to retrieve curLoc
                println("added a pin")
                addPin(loadlocation)
            }
            else{
                println("set curBtnBool to be false")
               curBtnBool = false
            }

            firstRetrieved = false
        }


    }
```

And this is my button action for attempting to animate the map to curPosition:

```
@IBAction func goToCurPos(sender: UIButton) {
    if curLocAccess {
        println("in the go to cur pos btn")
        firstRetrieved = true
        curBtnBool = true
        locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else{
        println("handle if location permission denied")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First solution:**

First of all, there is a pre-made user tracking bar button that you can add to a `UIToolbar`.

```
let userTrackingButton = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView:self.mapView)

self.toolbar.setItems([userTrackingButton])
```

That button behaves exactly like the one in the Maps app.

**Second solution:**

If you have to use your own button, then I would suggest you to change your logic.

1. Start tracking the user location from MKMapView

`self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true) 
// this will center on the user automatically.`

2. On `goToCurPos` button trigger, center your map view around the current user.

   Use the code you already have to center on the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user current location with `mapView.userLocation`.

Please try this code

```
@IBAction func goToCurPos(sender: UIButton) {
    mapView.setCenterCoordinate(mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate, animated: true)
}
```